# How do I sync Exchange contacts & calendar in Oreo?

Tags: 8.0-oreo

I'd like to sync my work contacts and calendar to my phone, but the option to add an Exchange account appears to have been removed in the version of Android I'm using (Nexus 5X running 8.0.0).

How can I do this? I'm not looking for a standalone app, I want something that will sync with the built-in dialer & calendar, like [CalDAV-Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dmfs.caldav.lib&hl=en) does for a CalDAV account.

I've tried installing [Exchange Services from APK Mirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/exchange-services/) but that didn't change anything.

Comment: So I've run into the same problem. Any solution to this by now?

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Outlook](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.outlook) now has the capability of syncing contacts. It's a heavyweight solution for just that feature.

I haven't found a way of doing calendars directly. If this is a cloud based exchange server that supports sharing calendars via iCal, it's possible to add that to a third-party calendar provider, then sync that to Android.